# Java JSwing using a method to add a panel to frame, how would I remove the panel?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jpanel

Hi I'm using a method to build a frame, the method takes parameters, so I was wondering if there was a work around, since I cannot remove it using the method without putting parameters. Here is some example code:

```
gameWindow.add(buildPlayersPanel(playersSelected));
```

So how would I then remove this panel, would I use the same method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would assume that `buildPlayersPanel(playersSelected)` returns an instance of some type of component, let's assume, for argument sake, a `JPanel`

You would then need to maintain a reference to the return result. To do this, you'll need to add an instance field to your class

```
private JPanel playersPanel;
```

When you build your UI, you'd need to assign the return result of `buildPlayersPanel(playersSelected)` to it...

```
playersPanel = buildPlayersPanel(playersSelected);
gameWindow.add(playersPanel);
```

And then, at some point in the future, when you want to remove it, you'd simply use the same reference

```
gameWindow.remove(playersPanel);
gameWindow.revalidate();
gameWindow.repaint();
```

Comment: Yeah that was exactly what I was trying to do, didn't realise it would be so simple, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

buildPlayersPanel.setVisible(false);

opps i had a spelling mistake last time so this should work

Comment: I should have mention the parameter that buildPlayersPanel takes is an integer

Comment: @tompenn I mean you could try that but if you are looking to make the panel invisible you would just do: buildPlayersPanel.setVisible(false);

Comment: @KeionBeats The OP is trying to tell you that they don't have a reference to  the result of the method call `buildPlayersPanel`